# To delete the documents from a collection if the join condition with some other collection matches?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

To delete the documents from a collection if the join condition with some other collection matches? e.g.,

```
DELETE FROM TABLE A WHERE A.KEY IN (SELECT KEY FROM TABLE B WHERE STATUS = ‘DELETED’)
```

Comment: What is your problem?